# Is there any way to save the checkbox's state of a program made in visual basic 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have made(designed) a program in Visual Basic 6.0,it consists of around 100 checkboxes ,the program does not require any code just a yes/no checkbox type program , but I want to save the checkbox state ,so that if a check box is in yes state then after restarting the program it's state remains conserved .
I have read about 
My.Settings.Save but I dont know how to use it , I am using Visual Basic 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Create keys in Registry, save each checkbox value on their checkbox Change event and load the status of each of them in the form Initialize event code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MyApp As String = "My Own App" 'put here your application name
Private Const Sett As String = "Settings"

Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    Dim chkBoxStatus As String
    chkBoxStatus = "CheckBox1"
    If Me.CheckBox1.value = True Then
        SaveSetting MyApp, Sett, chkBoxStatus, CStr(True)
    Else
        SaveSetting MyApp, Sett, chkBoxStatus, CStr(False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Do the same for all your check boxes.
And then:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'I do not remember well if VB6 uses Form_Initialize... You must adapt it accordingly.
  Dim regValue As String
  regValue = GetSetting(MyApp, Sett, "CheckBox1", "No value")
  If regValue <> "No value" Then Me.CheckBox1.value = CBool(regValue)
    'do the same for all checkboxes in discussion
    '.
    '.
End Sub
```

`"No value"` is returned if no value has been set in Registry (yet)...

Comment: It is not working,Here is the complete code of the program :
                                                                                                                             Option Explicit
Private Const MyApp As String = "Medicine"
Private Const Sett As String = "Settings"

Private Sub Check1_Click()
    Dim chkBoxStatus As String
    chkBoxStatus = "Check1"
    If Me.Check1.Value = True Then
        SaveSetting MyApp, Sett, chkBoxStatus, CStr(True)
    Else
        SaveSetting MyApp, Sett, chkBoxStatus, CStr(False)
    End If
End Sub                .....Continued(1)

Comment: Private Sub Form_Initialize()
  Dim regValue As String
  regValue = GetSetting(MyApp, Sett, "Check1", "No value")
  If regValue <> "No value" Then Me.Check1.Value = CBool(regValue)
End Sub
                                                                                                                       
  Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim regValue As String
  regValue = GetSetting(MyApp, Sett, "Check1", "No value")
  If regValue <> "No value" Then Me.Check1.Value = CBool(regValue)
End Sub
  -----------------------------END--------------

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: No need to put the same code in the Form_Load() event! If you do not like Initialize event, do it in Load event, but not twice.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma:  i'm afraid you did not understand the code. You must use `Check1_Change event`, not `Click` event...

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Each time you change the check box value, this is memorized in Registry and will be retrieved back when you will reload the form.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: In order to receive help, you must come with feedback. What "it is not working" means? Do you receive an error? Not any error, but nothing happens? In such a case I would suggest you to create two new buttons. In the first one code copy: `SaveSetting "TestApp", "Settings", "TestKey", "Write test"` and in the second one `MsgBox GetSetting("TestApp", "Settings", "TestKey", "No value")`. Run first button code and then the second one. What text does the message box show?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would have made all checkboxes a control array and would save their sate in a text file in some hidden place, like C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local. It would be a pretty small code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.